# Delphi XE6 firemonkey component alignment problems when added at runtime

Tags: ios, delphi, alignment, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

i wanto dynamic add 5 TLable in my iOS app.

like this

```
Procedure Form1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject)
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to 5 do
  begin
    with TLabel.Create(Self) do
    begin
      Parent := self;
      Align := TAlignLayout.Top;
      Height := 50;
      Text := IntToStr(I);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

i think the order is 12345, but I get 15432.

What can I do to get the desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must give a chance to the aligning algorithm to do what you want.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to 5 do
  begin
    with TLabel.Create(Self) do
    begin
      Parent := self;
      Align := TAlignLayout.alTop;
      Height := 50;
      Position.Y := I*Height; //add this line
      Text := IntToStr(I);
    end;
  end;
end;
```